# How can I know a native JS object hasn't been tampered with?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a plug-in that works on several shop systems. I found that sometimes they override native code. How can I be sure the code hasn't been altered? I don't intend to approach this from a security point of view - I assume users to be able to tamper will everything in the client side - but simply need to confirm that the current object I'm working with is the expected one. For instance, Google Chrome returns this when printing a method from the JSON object:

```
> JSON.stringify.toString()
< "function stringify() { [native code] }"
```

Is this a reliable way to check for tampering?

Answer (score 2):

If you're loading your JavaScript files up before anyone else then you have a number of tools avaliable to you [Object.preventExtensions()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions), [Object.seal()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) and [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze). This is more of a preventative measure.

They behave in slightly different ways but build on top of each other, this [article](http://piotrwalat.net/preventing-javascript-object-modification/) covers them quite nicely. In summary:

- preventExtensions: Disallows addition of properties
- seal: additionally prevent removal of existing properties
- freeze: additionally prevent modification of existing properties